# AndroidClientHandler and built-in Basic authentication

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, basic-authentication

I'm trying to make the built-in Basic Authentication work with the Xamarin AndroidClientHandler, but with no success. The code looks like this:

https://github.com/tieto-sternell/DemoAndroidBasicAuth/blob/c6bb4d547f2456e66b25daca4951957250278ac3/DemoAndroidBasicAuth/DemoAndroidBasicAuth.Droid/TestStuff.cs#L39-L43

```
        ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential(dummyUsername, dummyPassword);
        var handler = new AndroidClientHandler();
        handler.Credentials = credentials;
```

and:
https://github.com/tieto-sternell/DemoAndroidBasicAuth/blob/c6bb4d547f2456e66b25daca4951957250278ac3/DemoAndroidBasicAuth/DemoAndroidBasicAuth.Droid/TestStuff.cs#L19-L21

```
        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
        var badResponse = await client.GetAsync(basicUri) as AndroidHttpResponseMessage;
```

As you can see, it is pretty straight-forward and the code looks very similar to its working .Net equivalent. The response is 401, though, so I am doing something wrong.

Edit: As @jgoldberger points out below, it is possible to create the headers manually. This can be done either by adding a header to the message (github.com/tieto-sternell/DemoAndroidBasicAuth/blob/e7118f88a5b45f91207e90e9ea64c554d0ea9cd6/DemoAndroidBasicAuth/DemoAndroidBasicAuth.Droid/TestStuff.cs#L43-L48)

```
        byte[] byteToken = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dummyUsername + ":" + dummyPassword);
        var tokenValue = Convert.ToBase64String(byteToken);
        var token = "Basic " + tokenValue;

        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(basicUri));
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", token.ToString());
```

Or by adding a header to the HttpClient (github.com/tieto-sternell/DemoAndroidBasicAuth/blob/e7118f88a5b45f91207e90e9ea64c554d0ea9cd6/DemoAndroidBasicAuth/DemoAndroidBasicAuth.Droid/TestStuff.cs#L33-L37)

```
        byte[] byteToken = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dummyUsername + ":" + dummyPassword);
        var tokenValue = Convert.ToBase64String(byteToken);

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", tokenValue);
```

I don't think that this is how it is supposed to work, though. I mean, when is this (github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/0c3597869bc4493895e755bda8a26f778e4fe9e0/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AuthModuleBasic.cs#L50-L52)

```
        response += cred.UserName + ":" + cred.Password;

        return new Authorization ($"{AuthenticationType} {Convert.ToBase64String (Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (response))}");
```

code supposed to run in that case?

It looks to me as if the Authentication module isn't used.

The background story here is that I need to know how to make Basic work as part of a larger problem which involves Digest authentication and the custom "AuthenticationScheme.Unsupported", but we'll get there later when we've got the simpler basic auth scheme up and running.

Best regards,
Christian

Comment: I don't think you want to set those credentials on the AndroidClientHandler. See this guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/rest/

Comment: Hi @jgoldberger, and thanks for helping out! I think that link describes a workaround, but it doesn't solve the problem - which is to use the built-in authentication module for basic authentication. I couldn't fit my response in a comment, so please have a look at the edit I made to the original post.

Comment: Hi @Christian, Sorry that did not help. I don't think that is a "workaround," just perhaps not relevant for what you ultimately need to do. I might suggest that maybe you might try using the full Android Net stack rather than using HttpClient? It seems like you are looking to use some built in Android behavior which may be bypassed when using httpClient? Note: I am not familiar with using the full Android network stack and am not at all certain that would help you move forward.

Comment: Hi @jgoldberger, and thanks for following up! I'm not sure what you mean by using the complete Android Net stack. Do you mean opening connections along the lines of "            var connection = (Java.Net.HttpURLConnection)new Java.Net.URL(basicUri).OpenConnection();
"? If so, I think I will bypass the whole AndroidClientHandler, if I'm not mistaken?